# Avoid structure input in function

Tags: matlab

My question is: Should the use of structure as input for Matlab functions be avoided (if the goal is to have the best performances)? Also is there memory issues in using a struct as input as opposed to other type of input?

As a simple case, would it be better to do :

```
function test1(struct)
    var1 = struct.a
    var2 = struct.b
    var3 = struct.c
    ...
end
```

or is it better to do :

```
function test2(a,b,c)
    var1 = a
    var2 = b
    var3 = c
    ...
end
```

**EDIT**

Following the answer from [Dennis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22766601/2419003), I checked the profiler memory to get more infos. Here the result (note that `c = rand(1000)`):

```
┌───────────────────┬─────┬──────────┬──────────┬────────────────┬──────────────┬───────────────┬───────────┐
│Function Name      │Calls│Total Time│Self Time*│Allocated Memory│Freed Memory  │Self Memory    │Peak Memory│
├───────────────────┼─────┼──────────┼──────────┼────────────────┼──────────────┼───────────────┼───────────┤
│testfun            │1    │14.332 s  │1.603 s   │39149952.00 Kb  │39149828.00 Kb│-23470220.00 Kb│7832.00 Kb │
├───────────────────┼─────┼──────────┼──────────┼────────────────┼──────────────┼───────────────┼───────────┤
│testfun>teststruct │1000 │2.815 s   │2.815 s   │7828000.00 Kb   │7828000.00 Kb │0.00 Kb        │7828.00 Kb │
├───────────────────┼─────┼──────────┼──────────┼────────────────┼──────────────┼───────────────┼───────────┤
│testfun>testcell   │1000 │2.800 s   │2.800 s   │7828000.00 Kb   │7828000.00 Kb │0.00 Kb        │7828.00 Kb │
├───────────────────┼─────┼──────────┼──────────┼────────────────┼──────────────┼───────────────┼───────────┤
│test (MEX-function)│1000 │2.396 s   │2.396 s   │7830000.00 Kb   │0.00 Kb       │7830000.00 Kb  │7832.00 Kb │
├───────────────────┼─────┼──────────┼──────────┼────────────────┼──────────────┼───────────────┼───────────┤
│testfun>testvars   │1000 │2.395 s   │2.395 s   │7828000.00 Kb   │7828.00 Kb    │7820172.00 Kb  │7828.00 Kb │
├───────────────────┼─────┼──────────┼──────────┼────────────────┼──────────────┼───────────────┼───────────┤
│testfun>testmix    │1000 │2.323 s   │2.323 s   │7828000.00 Kb   │7828.00 Kb    │7820172.00 Kb  │7828.00 Kb │
└───────────────────┴─────┴──────────┴──────────┴────────────────┴──────────────┴───────────────┴───────────┘
```

What I don't understand is why is there more freed memory for the struct and cell function than for the 2 others?

Comment: from a user experience view, I would think the listed input arguments is better than a single `struct` when the number of input arguments is small. However, if you need to pass more than ~10 arguments, I would go with a `struct` that contains everything (like an object). Memory and speed wise, it should not make a significant difference.

Comment: Not really, no. Neither way involves data getting copied until(if) something is modified from the input.

Comment: @chappjc so the use of struct in input would only be bad if I start to add elements to the input struct (as opposed to just create new variables in the `test2` function)?

Comment: Add or modify elements, yes, I think so. But you'd have to test that out. Use `format debug` to see when copies are actually made in memory. Wish I had time to try it...

Comment: I am surprised to find that the columns are not properly explaned, as mentioned in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21997579/memory-profiling-of-matlab-columns-meaning). But as the peak memory is the same for all functions, I would say that it doesn't really matter which one you use from a memory point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when programming, doing something the 'simple' way is faster. This also seems to hold in this case.

Here is a function that  calls a function with a struct, with elements of a struct, and with separate variables. The first of these is somewhat slower.

```
function testfun
load testfuninput
a=1;
b=2;
c=rand(100);
s.a=a;
s.b=b;
s.c=c;
tic
for t = 1:1000
    teststruct(s)
end
toc
tic
for t = 1:1000
    testmix(s.a,s.b,s.c)
end
toc
tic
for t = 1:1000
    testvars(a,b,c)
end
toc
end

function teststruct(s)
s.c = s.c+1;
end
function testmix(a,b,c)
c = c + 1;
end
function testvars(a,b,c)
c = c + 1;
end
```

Will return something like:

```
Elapsed time is 0.026694 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.014959 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.014366 seconds.
```

So, the functions that take separate variables are faster.

That being said: Even if you do this a lot of times, it will only matter a fraction of a second. Hence for any nontrivial function the impact runtime should not outweigh other arguments.

---

Interesting sidenote: The speed of testvars is not really changed if you remove the assignment to the struct and just call `s.c_1;`.

Comment: I don't see the difference between testmix and testvars in what you posted, so hence, why is the elapsed time different?

Comment: Also, the `s.c = s.c + 1` call is slower than `c = c + 1;`. And is it not bad to modify the input inside the function?

Comment: @m_power It seems I made a mistake copying the results here. The timings were accurate though. Now look at the call to `testvars` and `testmix` and note that there is no serious difference in calculation time. I also found no significant speed difference between only reading `s.c` or assigning to it. There should be a memory difference but I did not test that.

Comment: I checked the memory with the profiler, you can look at my question edit.