# Memory profiling of MATLAB columns meaning

Tags: matlab, memory

I'm using MATLAB profile to observe memory using the command

```
profile -memory on
profile clear
% my code
profile report
```

and i got this table
[image]

1- i want to ask about the meaning of 
Allocated Memory,Freed Memory, SelfMemory, and Peak Memory

2- what is the meaning of negative self memory?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

After a quick google, it would seem that no-one knows, except perhaps MathWorks and they aren't telling. (I jest, but in truth I found very little information on the subject).

Logically however I would interpret the column names as follows:

Allocated memory = the total amount of memory allocated within the function and any it calls.

Freed memory = the total amount of memory released within the function and any it calls.

Peak Memory = the maximum amount of memory in use at any one time during the execution of the function.

Self Memory = the amount of memory used by the function, but not including any functions it calls.

I would hypothesize that a negative 'Self Memory' would indicate that the function frees more memory than it allocates. This could be that it has ownership of a piece of data passed to it, which it then clears. E.g.:

```
function A()
  foo = B();
  clear foo
end

function foo = B()
  foo = rand(10000,10000);
end
```

In the example above, the data is created in the call to `B` and since Matlab employs a lazy copy memory management, this case works pretty much as pass-by-reference for the return value. So, `B` allocates the memory, and `A` frees it.

Indeed, running that code with the profiling method in the question produces the following output, which supports my hypothesis.

[image: profile report]

Comment: I'd like to add that self memory is computed as follows: 1) we compute the "net" memory of a function using `net memory = total memory allocated - total memory freed`. 2) we compute a similar value for the function's children, `child memory = total memory allocated by children - total memory freed by children`. 3) `self memory = net memory - child memory`.